# Why does my pane have null Parent and null Scene?

Tags: java, javafx

I am new to `JavaFX` and I'm wondering why the Pane I have created in my fxml code doesn't have a Parent and a Scene.

This is the code;

```
// Code in Main
Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("sample.fxml"));
Scene scene = new Scene( root, 800, 600);

// Fxml code
<Pane fx:controller="sample.Controller" fx:id="pane"
      xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml">
</Pane>
```

When I call `scene.getRoot()`, I get the Pane I have created in the fxml. 
But calling `pane.getScene()` or `pane.getParent()` returns a null.

Am I thinking this in the wrong order? Is `getParent()` or `getScene()` supposed to be null because a Pane doesn't have a Scene but rather the Scene has a Root? 
And for instance a Stage has a Scene?

If so,
Is there a way for me to access the Scene or Parent that has this Pane as its Children, using that Pane?

(Also I expected `scene.getRoot()` to return the Parent rather than the Pane but I guess that has to do with the naming?)

Answer (score 0):

Calling `getParent()` on root will always return `null`, because root is top most element in `SceneGraph` in that case. Invoking `getScene()` before adding `Pane` to `Scene` will also return `null`, because scene property is not set on Pane component.

```
Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("test.fxml"));
System.out.println("Root getParent(): " + root.getParent());
System.out.println("Root getScene() before Scene: " + root.getScene());

Scene scene = new Scene(root, 600, 600);
System.out.println("Scene getRoot(): " + scene.getRoot());
System.out.println("Root getScene() after Scene: " + root.getScene());

stage.setScene(scene);
stage.show();
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Root getParent(): null
Root getScene() before Scene: null
Scene getRoot(): StackPane@547a5be4[styleClass=root]
Root getScene() after Scene: javafx.scene.Scene@24fd3643
```

Comment: How can I access the Scene using Pane from the controller then? I have to do it in initialize as I'm trying to add an onKeyPressed() to the Scene, and doing it in the Main doesn't let me interact with things in the Controller.

Comment: I have answered your first question. Do not edit existing question. Accept answer and ask another question if you have unrelated problem.

Comment: If you need access to Controller in Main, then dont use static `FXMLLoader.load()` method instead create instance of `FXMLLoader`. After loading `fxml` file use `getController()` method and get access to Controller.

Comment: I would do that if I didnt have to wait one and a half hours to post a question. Anyhow, posted new question, thanks for your answer.